# NameError for existing name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, nameerror

I get this **NameError** when executing my application.

```
NameError in CountriesController#index
undefined local variable or method `country_code' for Country(id: integer, name: string, country_code: string):Class
```

It's somewhere in this code, but I don't understand it.
I have my country_code, but It says it's inexistant.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates country_code, presence: true
   validates name, presence: true
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :country_code, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

You need to make the variables symbols